# Put value from CSV file in PHP variable?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a CSV file and would like to import this CSV file into my Wordpress database. With my basic PHP knowledge i made an import script that works fine for the easy:) work, but this is a bit harder.. I have a CSV file that have stored values in 1 cell and seperated them with a `|`

Now i would like:
-to extract each value in that cell (that is in between the `|`) and put it in a variable. I guess i need a 'foreach' function (which i am not familiar with) to create a $variable for each value found.
-once that is accomplished i need an 'foreach' function (i guess) in order to create  run a mysql_query for each value found / each variable created.

So lets say i have a record like this:

**id** **categories**
1 |1|2|5|7|

in my csv file. I need to be able to catch every value under 'categories' in a $variable and for every variable found i need to run a certrain mysql_query.

Hope i made myself clear. Is there anyone who can help me out on this?

Thanks,
Robbert

Comment: Have you had a look at [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/fgetcsv) and [`explode`](http://php.net/explode)?

Comment: thanks for your reply. Have it worked out. See my reply on the comment below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try yourself a little then show us your results.
Anyway, here are some hints for you.
First of all learn the PHP function 'explode', which stores the values into an array:

```
$myValues = explode('|', '1|1|2|5|7|');
```

Now you have an array filled with your values, you can check its data like this:

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r($myValues) . '</pre>';
```

Now use a foreach cycle to access its content and run your code:

```
foreach ($myValues as $singleValue) {
    // your code goes here, or:
    echo $singleValue;
}
```

Hope this helps.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Thanks a lot, this code extracted all the values from a certain desired cell:
`//tests
$myValues = explode('|', trim($data[14]));
echo '<pre>' . print_r($myValues) . '</pre>';
foreach ($myValues as $singleValue) {
    // your code goes here, or:
    echo $singleValue;
}
`